# Do Muses govern the arts?

Tags: greek, mythical-creatures

I thought Muses were patrons of all arts. I knew modern arts like photography or cinema would be attributed by extension to a "visual arts" muse. I thought there were "classical arts" painting and writing Muses.

I just re-read about them and found the 9 muses only covered things like poetry, music, singing, tragedy, comedy, history, and astronomy.

Are there no Muses for the novelist or the painter?

Comment: *I knew modern arts like photography or cinema would be attributed by extension to a "visual arts" muse* huh? The ancient greeks didn't have photography or cinema.

Comment: @Reed then why are you mentioning photography/cinema in a question about ancient greek mythology?

Comment: Modern arts always get folded into ancient categories, like cinema being the 7th Art. That's why i wrote "attributed by extension"

Answer (score 1):

The short answer for this question is no. There technically aren't Muses assigned to painting or novelists. However, that doesn't mean that they aren't governed by a God or Goddess.

Athena is known to be the Goddess of wisdom, courage, inspiration, civilization, law and justice, mathematics, strength, war strategy, **the arts**, **crafts, and skill**.

So if there isn't a Muse for a particular art form, Athena is your girl. Other Gods and Goddesses are also Patrons of certain art forms, like Apollo, but there is a Muse for the poetry and the song, unlike for painting.

Comment: i hadn't though about patron gods, but is it the same? the muses, at least in a platoniistic view, where conduits to the divine, they didn't inspire but possesse the artists. The artist was no the creator, but the vehicule through which gods expressed temselves via muses.